# How do I get credential providers set up with NuGet.core?

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to use Nuget.Core to access a nuget feed and I do have the credential provider but I'm still getting 401 not authorised. What Steps do I need to take to get nuget.core to use the credential providers and get access programmatically. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for several days - an [issue on the Nuget/Home](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7714) GitHub put me over the top and allowed me to create an API that fetches the Credential providers exactly as `NuGet.Client` does (which I mostly copied and pasted from)

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/cpyfferoen/74092a74b165e85aed5ca1d51973b9d2)

But basically

- Create a `CredentialService` and fill it with the credential providers on your machine

  - this is the hard part, so just do what `Nuget.Client` does
- Set `HttpHandlerResourceV3.CredentialService` with your service

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the NuGet.Core assembly you will need to create or use a class that implements the **NuGet.ICredentialProvider** interface.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using NuGet;

namespace Test
{
    class MyCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider
    {
        public ICredentials GetCredentials(Uri uri, IWebProxy proxy, CredentialType credentialType, bool retrying)
        {
            // TODO return the credentials...
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of that class and assign it to the **NuGet.HttpClient**.

```
NuGet.HttpClient.DefaultCredentialProvider = new MyCredentialProvider ();
```

Also NuGet provides a **SettingsCredentialProvider** class which you can use if you are storing your credentials in a NuGet.Config file. The SettingsCredentialProvider takes an ICredentialProvider instance in its constructor so you can pass your own implementation if you want to which will be used if no credential is found in the NuGet.Config file. Or instead you pass a **NullCredentialProvider** to the SettingsCredentialProvider class if you only want to use the information stored in the NuGet.Config file to be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So for that class, what do I use to return from the getCredentials() method? The credential provider I have was given in the of "https://{account}.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/nuget/client/CredentialProviderBundle.zip". I downloaded it, and it had a .VSS file and NuGet.exe. I'm not sure where to go from there, or how to use that to create the class you mentioned.

Comment: Well that is a different. From your original question I thought you were trying to use NuGet.Core from your application not use the credential providers provided by Microsoft. Those credential providers work with NuGet 3 and are automatically picked up and used by NuGet 3. There is documentation on [using these credential providers](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/credential-providers) which are basically executables that NuGet.exe will call to find a username and password.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me be able to do it from the Package Manager Console. One more question though, is there a way to do commands like "Get-Package -Source "nuget-feed" -ListAvailable" programmatically? The only things I could find are for powershell and cmd commands like echo.

Comment: You can find NuGet packages programmatically using NuGet.Core.dll. There is a simple example on the [NuGet blog](http://blog.nuget.org/20130520/Play-with-packages.html). The PackageRepository class also has some extension methods (e.g Search) which you can use to search for all packages rather than a specific one as shown in the example.