# 401 when accessing a VSTS feed using nuget.core

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to get nuget.core to use my PAT from VSTS.

I'm configuring the credentials like this:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("packageTester", "MY_PAT_STRING");
CredentialStore.Instance.Add(new Uri("https://myFEED.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BetaFeed/nuget/v3/index.json"), credentials);
```

(the name can be anything according to the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/nuget-exe))

And then querying the feed:

```
var repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository(                "https://myFEED.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BetaFeed/nuget/v3/index.json");
var packages = repo.GetPackages();
```

It's not working, I get a 401 error.

There are two other questions on the same subject:

- [Setting the Package Credentials using Nuget Core DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594613/setting-the-package-credentials-using-nuget-core-dll)
- [How do I get credential providers set up with NuGet.core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818973/how-do-i-get-credential-providers-set-up-with-nuget-core)

Neither work for me. I checked the `Nuget.Core` [source code](https://github.com/ctaggart/nuget/blob/master/src/Core/Http/HttpClient.cs) at github to see that it uses `CredentialStore`. But I still get 401 and can't figure out why.

**Edit:** It did work, Rebuilding the project didn't rebuild everything. However, the URL do not work. I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not connect to the feed specified at 'https://onetrueerror.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/BetaFeed/nuget/v3/index.json'. Please verify that the package source (located in the Package Manager Settings) is valid and ensure your network connectivity.'

If I remove `index.json` from the feed url I get the following error:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nuget.Core doesn't seem to support v3 of package feeds.
Thus the correct solution is:

### Configure credentials (before using PackageRepositoryFactory)

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("packageTester", "MY_PAT_STRING_FROM_VSTS");
CredentialStore.Instance.Add(new Uri("https://YourProject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YourFeedName/nuget/v2/"), credentials);
```

It works since the homebrewn `HttpClient` in Nuget.Core uses `HttpWebRequest` internally and configures it using `CredentialsCache`.

### Make sure to connect to version 2 of the feed.

VSTS gives you a feed URL like:

> https://YourProject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YourFeedName/nuget/v3/index.json

Change it to:

> https://YourProject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YourFeedName/nuget/v2/

.. when you use Nuget.Core.

### Complete code

```
//configure credentials
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("packageTester", "MY ");
CredentialStore.Instance.Add(new Uri("https://YourProject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YourFeedName/nuget/v3/"), credentials);

//download packages
var repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://YourProject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YourFeedName/nuget/v2/");
var packages = repo.GetPackages();
```

Comment: I was able to successfully list the packages in my VSTS feed using the example code above.  However, if I add 
`var manager = new PackageManager(repo, @"C:\SomeFolder");
var package = manager.SourceRepository.GetPackages().FirstOrDefault();
manager.InstallPackage(package.Id);`
I get a 401 when calling InstallPackage.  I even created a new PAT with All scopes enabled, but ti didn't make a difference.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try trimming the final forward slash in the v2 URL so it looks like this: https://YourProject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/YourFeedName/nuget/v2